# Terminal prompts immediately abort

Tags: stdin

When issuing commands that require a prompt midway (eg `apt install`), the prompt **immediately** aborts, as such:

```
self@localhost:~$ sudo apt install xterm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
After this operation, 2,023 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
self@localhost:~$
```

I've heard that this happens because applications are unable to read from stdin. So that's an issue.

I know that for apt, I can pass `-y` to skip the prompt. What can I do for other programmes that requires prompts but that provide no such option? What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: A workaround: `bash` then `exit` will fix the issue. Still, no idea what causes it.

Comment: Have you tried to log out and log back in? Reboot and try again? This feels like somebody has got into a bad state and either (or both) of the above should reset it.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? What happens If you use a different one (e.g. xterm, gnome-terminal, kterm, linux console)?

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l $(tty) ; lsof -V $(tty)` in your question ?

Comment: What will a simple `cat` at the prompt do?

Comment: I'd love to answer these questions but sadly I have no idea how to reproduce the issue. If it happens again, I'll have a wealth of info.